# Replace duplicate value in pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to replace the value from a panda dataframe that look like this [image: Table]

The multiindex dataframe has these columns :

```
MultiIndex([(  'Name',       ''),
            ('Link',       ''),
            (        'Category',       ''),
            (        'Id', ''),
            (        'Score',    'Min'),
            (        'Score',    'Normal'),
            (        'Score',    'Max'),
            (        'Result',    'Min'),
            (        'Result',    'Max'),
            (           'Result',       ''),
            (         'Pass',       '')],
```

I want the A, B, C, and D to be replaced with blanks if they have duplicates

I have tried to use
`df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Name']),['Name']]=''` 
but i think it is not for multiindex dataframe because it gives me
`KeyError: Index(['Name'], dtype='object')`

I was expecting the dataframe will look like this [image: expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Name', '')])
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], columns=idx)
```

`df`

```
    Name

0   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
```

checking `df` have multiindex

`df.columns`

```
MultiIndex([('Name', '')],
           )
```

**Code**

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=[('Name', '')]), ('Name', '')] = ''
```

`df`

```
    Name

0   A
1   
2   B
3
```

apply to your dataset

Answer (score 3):

First select the column then use duplicated

```
for c in ('Name', 'Category'):
    df.loc[df[c].duplicated(), c] = ''
```

---

```
  Name Link Category
                    
0    A    -        C
1         -         
2    B    -        D
3         -
```